# WYSIWYG - QueryCommands

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

как использовать queryCommands? P.S. хочу в редакторе изменять состояние кнопок в зависимости от текущего выделения и положения курсора

Answer (score 1):

Если что-то самописное, то можно пробовать document.getSelection()

Если нет - [какой именно редактор используете?](https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors)